# Adding a layout editor to our edit action page

Tags: orchardcms

We have a custom action that follows some custom workflow logic behind the scenes and want to add a layout to the data captured to the settings. I was able to add a checkbox to enable the layout (its an optional thing) associated with the custom action but I cant seem to find how to add a layout editor to our form?

```
var f = shapeFactory.Form(
    Id: "ActionForm",
    _Outcomes: shapeFactory.TextBox(Id: "action-text-box", Name: "Action", Title: T("Action")),
    _HasLayout: shapeFactory.CheckBox(Id: "HasLayout", Name: "HasLayout", Title: T("Uses Layout"), Value: "true"),
    //_Layout: shapeFactory.Parts_Layout_Edit(Id: "Layout", Name: "Layout", Title: T("Layout"))
    );
```

This is where I am at at the moment (the last line is commented because the part name is incorrect), but I feel I am missing some core concept for adding the layout editor... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after much experimentation.
Add to the form description

```
_Form: shapeFactory.EditorTemplate(Id: "Form", Name: "Form", Title: T("From"), TemplateName: "Parts.Layout", Prefix: "LayoutPart",
    Model: new LayoutPartViewModel {
        LayoutEditor = layoutEditorFactory.Create("", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    })
```

and then you need to add a script to the form page in order to reload the layout editor with the bound data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var layoutEditorData = JSON.parse($("[name$='.LayoutEditor.Data']").val());
    window.layoutEditor = new LayoutEditor.Editor(window.layoutEditor.config, layoutEditorData);
});
```